# Controlling when drawing finishes in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

When drawing a polygon in openlayers, it seems like the default behavior is to complete the polygon when either the first vertex is clicked again, or when the last vertex drawn is clicked again.  Is there anyway to prevent the drawing from finishing when the last vertex drawn is clicked, so that the only way to finish the drawing is by clicking again on the first vertex of the polygon?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving this by setting the finishCondition for the draw interaction to ol.events.condition.never.  Then I do a check for whether I am clicking on the first point I drew, in which case I call the finishDrawing() function.

Comment: Even better would be to use a custom condition which checks whether you clicked the first point, and return true only in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You have to override this method

```
/**
 * Determine if an event is within the snapping tolerance of the start coord.
 * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} event Event.
 * @return {boolean} The event is within the snapping tolerance of the start.
 * @private
 */
ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.atFinish_ = function(event) {
```

Here, the potentiallyFinishCoordinates variable containes the "candidates" point used to determine if the last click is "at finish" of the drawing.

For the polygon case, that variable contains the first and the last drawn points.

```
potentiallyFinishCoordinates = [this.sketchCoords_[0][0],
        this.sketchCoords_[0][this.sketchCoords_[0].length - 2]];
```

Try removing the second element of that array.

Comment: Overriding internal private methods is never a good idea. It will make your app break when you update OpenLayers.